# Background window popup

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am opening up a new window popup and I want to keep it in background and keep focus on my current window. I am doing something like this but it doesn't work.

```
var currentWindow = window;
var newWindow = window.open("http://www.example.com");
currentWindow.focus();
```

I will appreciate suggestions or any kind of help.

Comment: Most browsers these days block this kind of behavior as it smells of popunder adverts.  Its unfortunate as there are *some* legitimate reasons to desire this behavior in enterprise web apps.

Answer (score 1):

If the window doesn't ever need to be seen, you could instead use a hidden iframe.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "http://xyz.com";
iframe.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I need to open a window as its a cross domain call. I can't do it using an iframe because of browser security.

Answer (score -1):

You can blur the background window

```
var win = window.open('http://www.xyz.com');
win.blur();
window.focus();
```

This should work for you in the application

Comment: Well in that case in the window being opened if you have control over that one, call window.opener.focus()

Comment: That doesn't work either.Window.opener returns me the object but that focus doesn't do anything.

Comment: Which browser are you using? and are there any security policies running on it, since it works fine here using Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X Snow Lepord

Comment: I am using Chrome, IE9 on Windows 7.